# Any way to make a query with more then 2000 bindings?

Tags: sql, sql-server, laravel, laravel-4

developers, I need again your help.
I work with a very big MS SQL database, records in this db more than 1kk. 
So, when i try to make query, i get error with limiting binding of 2100 parameters. I try to make also query with DB::raw, but it doesn't help. 
I not want to make a pure SQL query. Any solutions?

```
$product_codes = array_slice($product_codes, 0, 1999); // in original $product_codes about 4k codes.
$wheels = Wheel::select(array('Wheel_Size'))->whereIn('Product_code', $product_codes)->lists('Wheel_Size');
```

Answer (score 0):

Write the following code inside  vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php in the WhereIn method after the check has been made to see whether $values is an instance of Closure (Line number 672 in my project)

`if(count($values)>800)
{
    return $this->whereRaw($column. ' IN ('.implode(',', $values).')');
}`